# Rotate an image X degrees C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, rotation

This has been bothering me for ages, I just want a simple method that rotates an image X degrees. (this is for a turret defense game in which the turrets need to shoot a certain direction)

I want something like this:

```
public Image getRotatedImage(Image img, float angle)
{
     //Code here to rotate the image
     return img
}
```

All of this in c# wpf ofcourse and dynamically.. Hope you guys can help me out here :D

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Don't use code to change your image.  Let WPF rotate it for you using a RotateTransform.

```
<Image ...>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="45" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image >
```

Or apply a RotateTransform to your image in code:

```
RotateTransform rotateTransform = new RotateTransform(45);
img.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
```

Comment: Thank you man! You're the first to explain this without like 45 lines of code :) I would give you an upvote, but i don't have enough rep :P

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, what the first reply said! ;) This is actually the only post that explains the angle change without animation! Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to do this continuously? This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Thomas, by *continuously* do you mean animation? If so, there is a lot of information out there on animation, but is not answered here. This answer was for a static rotation of an image or perhaps binding the rotation to a view model, but not true wpf animation.