# "By" RenderTransform Angle Property Ignored on Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rotation

I've consulted a number of sources on rotating an image using the WPF's declarative XAML format, namely, this pretty solid blog post, [Rotate an Image in WPF Using Just XAML](http://adamprescott.net/2012/08/29/rotate-an-image-in-wpf-using-just-xaml/), and an SO question: [wpf rotate image around center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13034201/3469725).

As a result, my XAML - which *is* rotating the image - looks like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Spinner" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Image.RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="13" CenterY="13" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                        By="90"
                                        To="360"
                                        Duration="0:0:4"
                                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

The problem I am having is that the rotation appears fluid and continuous, rather than by the 90 deg. specified by the `By` property. I am attempting to rotate a particular portion of the image to a particular quadrant on each animation.

The answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23699219/3469725, gets close to what I need; however, the image is rotated once and is not continuously animated.

Is this possible with WPF and is the `By` property the correct property to be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was approaching this in an entirely "wrong" way. Here is my solution which does *not* use the `DoubleAnimation` XAML property, but, rather, the `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` - an entirely different approach. For what I am attempting to do - rotate by 90 deg. intervals - this is  a simple solution that does not require use of easing and gives more of a "snapping" effect.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                    Duration="0:0:4"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="180"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="270"/>
                            <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="360"/>
                        </DoubleKeyFrameCollection>
                   </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
      </Trigger.EnterActions>
  </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `To` + `By` combination (at least for [`DoubleAnimation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.by.aspx)).

It's not really clear what you expect. You have initial value (e.g. `0`) and you set `Duration` and `To`, which is enough to calculate how animation will change the angle value. `By` is meaningless disregards which value you will set.

If you need some kind of *steps*, then you have to do it with series of fast animations: rotate 90°, wait (or use easing function), rotate another 90°, etc.

```
<Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
    <DoubleAnimation To="90" Duration="0:0:1" ... >
        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            <BounceEase Bounces="2" EasingMode="EaseOut" Bounciness="1.8" />
        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
    </DoubleAnimation>
    ... more animations to rotate for 360 degrees if steps need different animation
    ... otherwise use `By` (without `To`) and repeat above animation it indefinitely
</Storyboard>
```

See for more about [`easing functions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee308751(v=vs.100).aspx). Just try some until you understand how they work and find the best fitting for your animation.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the easing function? I am looking for how to step, yes.

Comment: It's pretty easy, see edit. I like myself `ElasticEase` (spring-like effect).

Comment: doesn't just setting "By" reset the animation to it's original position after the animation?

Comment: Nope. `By` is used when you can't/don't want to specify `To`. You have to read more about animations. Finished animation (unless removed) can hold the last value or not. Read about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752312(v=vs.100).aspx#fillbehaviorsection). But in this case animation is indefinite. Btw, 0° = 360 ° = 720° = ... until `int32.MaxValue`. I wouldn't worry about overflow (if you decide to use `By`).

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thank you. I found something closer to what I was looking for (which I have posted as an answer). I will +1 your answer, though.